# How do I indicate which other site in the SE Network when voting to close?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

When I vote to close, it is often because the question belongs on another network. However, when I select that option as a reason when voting to close, the only other site that is displayed as an option is the meta site.

How do I pick another site?

---

Edit, September 2021

This question was closed because it's a duplicate of another question raised six years ago. The reason for not doing anything about it all those years ago was that ELL was in beta. Maybe it's time to reconsider doing something about this... even just adding another button labelled **Other** which doesn't automatically move the question, but still flags it for closure/moderator attention.

Comment: A better duplicate would be [Why does another SE site option only include ELL Meta SE?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5347/9161)

Comment: This question predates that one by 5 years

Answer (score 3):

A question being on topic on another site in the StackExchange network is not a reason to close it, unless it is a question about the working of the site.

A question may be on topic on several different sites.  If it is not appropriate for ELL then that is the closure reason. If you think is might be appropriate for another site you might mention that in the closure comment

> Hello @user  Your question is asking us to analyse a piece of literature, and that goes beyond the scope of English Language Learners. See https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic  However our sister site [literature.se] would welcome your question.

The closure reason is that literary analysis is off-topic. You don't close because it is on topic on literature.se

A question might be on topic on two different sites

> Hello @user Your question asks about the etymology of a word. You might get better answers on our sister site [english.se]  You might want to delete this question and ask it on that site.

You should not close an on-topic etymology question (one that is relevant to learning English)