# Why does another SE site option only include ELL Meta SE?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

So there is [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/264678/urge-someone-in-the-kindest-way-possible) question on main site today which in Justin's opinion and my opinion too, better fitted another SE site altogether. I was trying to flag the question so that moderators could easily locate it and migrate it to other sites accordingly. However, what happened is this:

1. I clicked the flag button/link below the question.
2. I selected the option of **needs improvement**.
3. Thereafter, the **A community-specific reason** option.
4. Then finally, **This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network**

There I was presented with only one option of choosing to migrate, which is here (ELL Meta SE). Why is this so? I mean shouldn't all users (maybe after a certain reputation limit is reached) be given the privilege of choosing the SE site they deem fit? I mean not everyone will go around flagging questions, and not everyone flags the same question over and over again. Is this a bug in the site? Or does the community not trust low-rep users to do the right thing?

Comment: One's experience and understanding of one Stack does not suggest similar comprehension of the standards of other Stacks, and the last thing the network needs is for questions to be constantly shunted around. Moreover, it is possible for a good question to be valid on multiple Stacks, although the answers would likely focus on different things.

experience and understanding of all Stacks. In fact, it would be nigh impossible these days, considering how many Stacks there are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These options are called [migration paths](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261196/295232) and sites can have five of them (one of them must be the site's own meta). Requests for migration to another site are to be carried out by **flagging the question for moderator attention**, as indicated in the [FAQ about migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/295232) (which also contains some nice flowcharts):

> If you think so, you can flag the question for moderator attention and request that they migrate it for you. Simply explain in the reason which site you want it to be migrated.

Also, the FAQ mentions:

> If the question is likely to be closed or deleted on the destination site anyway, don't bother migrating it. Just vote to close it normally and advise the OP of the other site in the comments. If they decide to improve the question, then they can go post it over there, or they can edit their question so it's on-topic on the original site.

I'm not sure that question meets the quality standards of those sites, but it can perhaps be edited into a proper shape.

---

We don't get much of these flags asking for migration, as is evident from the [migration statistics](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) (only visible for 10k users, but here is a screenshot:

[image]

The left column indicates we get a lot of questions from English Language & Usage (logical, they do have a migration path to our site); on the contrary, we almost never migrate questions away. Such situations are so rare (and diverse) that moderator flags sufficiently support the process.

Comment: I think the "rejected" migration to Language Learning, suggested by LL's moderator in a flag, was actually a [successful migration](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/262392/revisions). Weird it shows "100% rejected".

Comment: So henceforth if I need to flag for migration, then I must select, _flag question for moderator attention_, did I get it correct?

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh correct.